# Como usar fgets con una arreglo de cadenas tipo puntero en c

Tags: c, archivo

Hola buenos dias a todos, tengo un problema al usar la funcion `fgets` en Lenguaje C. Pero tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un archivo llamado `clientes.txt`, el cual tiene la siguiente info:

```
Pedro Pérez 7569984 1 500000 100000
Luisa García 8987565 1 1.500000 250000
Josefa Cardenas 1565988 1 2700000 580000
María González 5456748 0 850000 0
```

La idea es guargar cada linea en un Arreglo de un puntero del tipo `char`, pero por alguna razon no me lo permite, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    FILE * F = fopen("clientes.txt", "r");
    char * lineas[4];
    int i = 0;
    for (i; i < 4; i++){
        fgets(lineas[i], 100, F);
        printf("\n%s", lineas[i]);
    }
    
    fclose(F);

    printf("\nAnnadiendo Linea...");
    return 0;
}
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias <3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás intentando acceder a un puntero sin inicializar.

Como sabrás, cuando declaras una variable, esta tiene basura. Necesitas inicializarla. Como es un arreglo de punteros, deberías establecerlos en 0 o la dirección de memoria deseada.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    lineas[i] = 0;
}
```

En segundo lugar, un puntero solo contiene una dirección de memoria donde se leerán y escribirán los datos (mediante desreferenciación). Por lo que necesitas usar direcciones válidas.

Estas pueden ser las de otras variables, por ejemplo:

```
char linea1[100] = "";
char linea2[100] = "";
char linea3[100] = "";

lineas[0] = linea1; 
lineas[1] = linea2;
lineas[2] = linea3;
```

O memoria dinámica. Necesitarás asignarla con [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) y no olvides borrarla con [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free):

```
lineas[0] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100); 
lineas[1] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
lineas[2] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);

// Haz lo que tengas que hacer
...

// Liberas la memoria
free(lineas[0]);
free(lineas[1]);
free(lineas[2]);
```

Una vez que tienes un lugar donde guardar lo que leas, sí puedes hacerlo.

---

Lo más simple es usar la memoria del stack (el primer ejemplo).

Pero si quieres ocupar solo la memoria necesaria, con números desconocidos de líneas y longitud, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
FILE* archivo = fopen("clientes.txt", "r");

if (!archivo) {
    printf("No se puede leer");
    return 0;
}

// Ir al final
fseek(archivo, 0, SEEK_END);
int tamano = ftell(archivo);

char* contenido = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * tamano);

// Leer contenido
rewind(archivo);
fread(contenido, sizeof(char), tamano, archivo);
fclose(archivo);

int nLineas = 0;

// Contar cuantas líneas hay
for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++) {
    if (contenido[i] == '\n') {
        nLineas++;
    }
}

char** lineas = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * nLineas);
int lineaActual = 0;
int inicioLinea = 0;

// Contar tamaño de cada línea y copiar su contenido
for (int i = 0; i < tamano; i++) {
    if (contenido[i] == '\n') {
        int tamanoLineaActual = i - inicioLinea;
        lineas[lineaActual] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (tamanoLineaActual + 1));
        lineas[lineaActual][tamanoLineaActual] = 0;

        char* inicio = contenido + inicioLinea;
        strncpy(lineas[lineaActual], inicio, tamanoLineaActual);

        inicioLinea = i + 1;
        lineaActual++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < nLineas; i++) {
    printf("\n%s", lineas[i]);
}

// Liberar memoria
for (int i = 0; i < nLineas; i++) {
    free(lineas[i]);
}
free(lineas);
free(contenido);
```

En este caso se trabaja más con la memoria principal, pero podrías hacer un procedimiento similar que funcione más leyendo el archivo.

Comment: Gracias por la información, me ha quedado muy claro 